# All digits in int are divisible by certain int

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to count all numbers between two ints(a and b), where all of the digits are divisible with another int(k) and 0 counts as divisible.Here is what I've made so far, but it is looping forever.

```
for (int i = a; i<=b; i++){
   while (i < 10) {
      digit = i % 10;
      if(digit % k == 0  || digit == 0){
         count ++;
      }
      i = i / 10;
   }
}
```

Also I was thinking about comparing if all of the digits were divisible by counting them and comparing with number of digits `int length = (int)Math.Log10(Math.Abs(number)) + 1;`

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When does your `while` loop end?

Comment: Take paper and pencil and perform your program step by step, or (even better) use debugger for this very purpose.

Comment: btw, `digit == 0` is already included in this condition `digit % k == 0`, unless k is 0

Comment: One note: read about [integer arithmetic](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/DataBasics/Mathoperators.htm) and you will learn that for all `i<10` the result of `i = i / 10;` will always be zero.  This is not your main or only problem, though.

Comment: Well, part of the problem is that you don't stop looping after a match, so you're counting the number of matching digits in all numbers between a and b. That will expand the run time, as well as produce an incorrect result. Additionally, you're modifying the loop variable, which will cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: I understand that now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 2;
        int b = 150;
        int k = 3;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            boolean isDivisible = true;
            int num = i;
            while (num != 0) {
                int digit = num % 10;
                if (digit % k != 0) {
                    isDivisible = false;
                    break;
                }
                num /= 10;
            }
            if (isDivisible) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(i+" is one such number.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total " + count + " numbers are divisible by " + k);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was great and quick, now I get it :)
I cannot upvote, because my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 3):

Once you get in to your `while` block you're never going to get out of it. The `while` condition is when `i` less than 10. You're dividing `i` by 10 at the end of the `whole` block. `i` will never have a chance of getting above 10.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are quite a few things going on here, so we'll take this a piece at a time.

```
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++){

   // This line is part of the biggest problem. This will cause the
   // loop to skip entirely when you start with a >= 10. I'm assuming
   // this is not the case, as you are seeing an infinite loop - which
   // will happen when a < 10, for reasons I'll show below.
   while (i < 10) {
      digit = i % 10;
      if(digit % k == 0  || digit == 0){
         count ++;

         // A missing line here will cause you to get incorrect 
         // results. You don't terminate the loop, so what you are 
         // actually counting is every digit that is divisible by k 
         // in every number between a and b.
      }

      // This is the other part of the biggest problem. This line 
      // causes the infinite loop because you are modifying the 
      // variable you are using as the loop counter. Mutable state is
      // tricky like that.
      i = i / 10;
   }
}
```

It's possible to re-write this with minimal changes, but there are some improvements you can make that will provide a more readable result. This code is untested, but does compile, and should get you most of the way there.

```
// Extracting this out into a function is often a good idea.
private int countOfNumbersWithAllDigitsDivisibleByN(final int modBy, final int start, final int end) {
    int count = 0;

    // I prefer += to ++, as each statement should do only one thing,
    // it's easier to reason about
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {

        // Pulling this into a separate function prevents leaking
        // state, which was the bulk of the issue in the original.
        // Ternary if adds 1 or 0, depending on the result of the
        // method call. When the methods are named sensibly, I find
        // this can be more readable than a regular if construct.
        count += ifAllDigitsDivisibleByN(modBy, i) ? 1 : 0;
    } 
    return count;
}

private boolean ifAllDigitsDivisibleByN(final int modBy, final int i) {
    // For smaller numbers, this won't make much of a difference, but
    // in principle, there's no real reason to check every instance of 
    // a particular digit.
    for(Integer digit : uniqueDigitsInN(i)) {
        if ( !isDigitDivisibleBy(modBy, digit) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// The switch to Integer is to avoid Java's auto-boxing, which 
// can get expensive inside of a tight loop.
private boolean isDigitDivisibleBy(final Integer modBy, final Integer digit) {
    // Always include parens to group sub-expressions, forgetting the 
    // precedence rules between && and || is a good way to introduce 
    // bugs.
    return digit == 0 || (digit % modBy == 0);
}

private Set<Integer> uniqueDigitsInN(final int number) {
   // Sets are an easy and efficient way to cull duplicates.
   Set<Integer> digitsInN = new HashSet<>();
   for (int n = number; n != 0; n /= 10) {
       digitsInN.add(n % 10);
   }
   return digitsInN;
}
```